# How to add slack team channel in terraform stackdriver monitoring template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to add existing added google stackdriver slack channel into stackdriver alert template using terraform. Alert policy has been create successfully but when I try to add slack channel into same template, can't create the alert policy with slack channel. it's giving error. Kindly suggest with the appropriate step.

```
resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "slack1" {
  display_name = "#xxxx"
  type = "slack"
  labels = {
    auth_token = "xxxxx"
    channel_name = "#xxxxx"
  }
}

resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "slack2" {
  display_name = "#xxxx"
  type = "slack"
  labels = {
    auth_token = "xxxxxxxxx"
    channel_name = "#xxxx"
  }
}


resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy0" {
  display_name = "xxxxxx"
  combiner = "OR"
  conditions {
    display_name = "xxxxxxx"
    condition_threshold {
      filter = "xxxxxx"" 
      duration = "300s"
      comparison = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = 0.60
      trigger {
          count = 1
      }
      aggregations {
        alignment_period = "60s"
        per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_MEAN"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_SUM"
      }
    }
  }
  documentation {
    content = "xxxxxxx."
  }

  notification_channels = [
    "${google_monitoring_notification_channel.slack.slack1.name}",
  ]
}

resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy1" {
  display_name = "xxxx"
  combiner = "OR"
  conditions {
    display_name = "XXXXXX"
    condition_threshold {
      filter = "xxxxxxx""
      duration = "60s"
      comparison = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = 1024
      trigger {
          count = 1
      }
      aggregations {
        alignment_period = "60s"
        per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_MEAN"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_SUM"
      }
    }
  }
  documentation {
    content = "xxxx"
  }

  notification_channels = [
    "${google_monitoring_notification_channel.slack.slack2.name}",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please update this question with the exact error you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

```
notification_channels = [
"${google_monitoring_notification_channel.slack.slack2.name}",
]
```

Here is the mistake, the syntax of the entries in this field is *projects/[PROJECT_ID]/notificationChannels/[CHANNEL_ID]*

Just remove the first "slack" from the code and it will be fine.

I'm almost sure that you can't even create a proper slack channel at the moment because of a change in the auth method in slack API, I suggest do it in the console manually, after this try 
"gcloud alpha monitoring channels list" to take the proper value of the channel